# SessionScoped Managed Beans Lyfecycle issue

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, javabeans, managed, session-scope

I am a newbie having problem with MB JSF Lifecycle :

I got 2 Session Mananaged Beans (MB), 1 for input ant the othe for validation and DB writing.
In the ValidationData MB, I inject the InputData MB :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "validationData")
@SessionScoped
public class Validation implements Serializable {
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{inputData}")
    private InputData inputData
    ...
```

At the end of the validation process I kill the InputData MBean that way :

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
    String sessionId = session.getId();
    session.removeAttribute("inputData");
```

My problem is that for the second validation, I apparently still get the data of my first inputData Bean in My validatioNData Bean. (I saw the preDestroy instruction of my first inputData MBean apres my first validation).

Any Help ???

Thanks
GLO

Comment: You should not have to take care of removing managed beans from any scope. Removing a bean from the session map is not the same as ultimately destroying it (even if a @PreDestroy annotated method is called), so this may be the reason why you are facing old values. I suggest to implement a solution that is not depending on the removal of a session scoped bean. You may want to move the validation logic to a distinct Validator, see https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html for this.